Wedderburn-Artin theorem and primitive idempotents
Let $A$ be a simple Artinian $K$-algebra. This algebra contains a minimal left ideal $M$ which can be seen as a simple left $A$-module. By Schur's lemma, $D^{op}:=\text{End}_A(M)$ is a $K$-division algebra. Consequently, $M$ is a left $D^{op}$-vector space or right $D$-vector space. I prefer to view the latter since then $M={}_AM_D$ becomes a bimodule.
I want to prove that, for any primitive idempotent $e$ of $A$, $$eAe \cong D$$ as right $D$-vector space. Would you check the rigor of my proof?
Proof
By Wedderburn-Artin theorem, we have
the $K$-algebra isomorphism
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:W-a}
    A\cong \text{Mat}_r(D). \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \text{(WA)}
\end{equation}
In the matrix algebra $\text{Mat}_r\left(D\right)$, there are $r$ primitive idempotents, forming a unique maximal set of mutually orthogonal elements. This set consists of diagonal matrices with $1_D$ in a single diagonal position and zeros elsewhere. By (WA), every maximal set $\mathcal{E}$ of mutually orthogonal primitive idempotents in $A$ corresponds to this unique set in $\text{Mat}_r\left(D\right)$. Consequently, for every primitive idempotent $e$ of $A$, there exists a unique $\mathcal{E}$ such that $e \in \mathcal{E}$.
Suppose $e$ corresponds to a primitive idempotent element $E_{ii}$ in $\text{Mat}_r(D)$. The isomorphism (WA) and the fact that \begin{equation*}
E_{ii} \text{Mat}_r(D) E_{ii} \cong D
\end{equation*}
imply $eAe \cong D$.
If this proof is fine, I would appreciate it if you could suggest something simpler.

It is not true that there is a unique maximal set of orthogonal idempotents: rather, any such family is conjugate to this one.

Firstly, the set of idempotents you are talking about is by no means unique with that property (as Captain Lama mentioned in the comments.)
Secondly, I think you'd rather mean $eAe\cong D$ as rings.  Then, of course, it's the same right $D$ space no matter how you look at it.
Thirdly,  it seems overkill to jump straight to matrices.
With the last point in mind, let's leverage the fact that $_AA$ is a semisimple module. This gets you two things:

The definition of primitive idempotent is that $Ae$ is a nonzero irreducible submodule of $_AA$.  Then $Ae$ is an irreducible semisimple submodule of $_AA$, which is necessarily a simple submodule.

All simple left ideals of $A$ are mutually isomorphic. (An elementary exercise. The socle of $A$ can't have multiple isotypes in a simple Artinian ring.)


So $Ae\cong M$ as left $A$ modules, and hence $End(_AAe)\cong End(_AM)$ as rings. Then since $End(_AAe)\cong (eAe)^{op}$ as rings, you would have that $(eAe)^{op}\cong D^{op}$ and also $eAe\cong D$ (as rings.)

Thank you. I just do not know about your last line. How do you say $\text{End}\left({}_AAe\right) \cong (eAe)^{op}$?? What is its proof?

@khashayar Take a shot at it: the homomorphism to try is the one that maps $eae$ to the map $xe\mapsto xe(eae)$.
